# Did Michael McCaul claim intel briefers told him Tucker Carlson is a Russian agent?

Tags: united-states, politics, russia

Fox News’ Tucker Carlson just said [this](https://twitter.com/amfirebrand/status/1602724764002537475?s=46&t=1zXkF9x6mJ_Kgp_rl8fdVw) on the Tulsi Gabbard Show:

> Second thing, Michael McCaul […] I got into an argument with him once last year on the phone.  He had told somebody that I was a Russian agent or something. […] He said “Whoa whoa whoa, I just got that - that’s what the intel briefers told me, that you were working for Russia.” … He’s like “Well, they had all kinds of corroborating evidence.”

This refers to Republican Congressman [Michael McCaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_McCaul).

Did Congressman McCaul claim that intelligence community briefers told him that Carlson is a Russian agent?

Comment: This question seems to be about what was said in a private conversation between Carlson and McCaul. You have found Carlson's version. If McCaul disagrees with it, this question is going to be unanswerable. If McCaul agrees with it, this question is going to be rather uninteresting. I am worried, either way, you won't be satisfied with the answer. Is there another question here?

Comment: I thought this was the best way to ask the question, since if I ask directly whether intel briefers told this to McCaul, I’d be asking about a claim that may not have even been made.  But I’m open to suggestions.